# How to check that When CHECKDB run

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am showing an alert that CHECKDB is executed or not in my application(If run then how many days before its run).But problem is that if some one execute CHECKFILEGROUP,it also update the value of "dbi_dbccLastKnownGood" so i am unable to identify that CHECKDB is executed or not.

Can we check this without check value of "dbi_dbccLastKnownGood" ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually i want to show some alert on my application that database checked with DBCC CHECKDB or not.I have implement with the value of dbi_dbccLastKnownGood but same value update with CHECKFILEGROUP also. SO some time if user checked database with CHECKFILEGROUP then my alert disappear.